# How can I get a device's geolocation in React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

My app needs to access the user's coordinates, but I can't find a way to do this. I'm using Expo, but I'd like to avoid using any Expo libraries as I plan to eject it later and don't want to run into issues when I do so.

I've tried installing react-native-geolocation-service, but I get the following error:

```
'new NativeEventEmitter()' requires a non-null argument.
```

Is there any way I can get the device's coordinates without using an Expo library?

Comment: https://reactnative.directory/?search=geolocation

Comment: https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/issues/346 ?

Answer (score 0):

For expo, they have their own package for getting the location

Link: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/

```
expo install expo-location
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```